# Infinite loop popoverController IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Greetings fellow Stackoverflowians,

I have ran into a very strange error which I have been pulling my hair out for the past week over, I believe there is an infinite loop happening with the popoverController however the app is not using the uipopoverController.

I can't find where the problem is originating as when i'm debugging we get to a certain point then goes into memory locations until the app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV).

This is the crash log we are getting, any help on this issue would be fantastic.
Full stack trace can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5a1s9kuh1c8pyy/StackTrace.text

```
Process:         AppName [20577]
Path:            /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:      AppName
Version:         0
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd_sim [19259]
Responsible:     launchd_sim [19259]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2014-08-22 14:47:11.148 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  1AB3A959-D816-7933-9C74-7B70BD54030D

Sleep/Wake UUID: EE324FAB-2B7D-4C68-9381-CDD99B89DE38

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000bf7ffffc

VM Regions Near 0xbf7ffffc:
    Stack                  00000000b03a2000-00000000b03b2000 [   64K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--> Stack                  00000000bc000000-00000000bf800000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
    Stack                  00000000bf800000-00000000c0000000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 463.9.41, iPhone OS 7.1 (iPad/11D167)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e71286 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e6f5ec kill$UNIX2003 + 32
2   libsystem_sim_c.dylib           0x03b7635b raise + 26
3   AppName                         0x001d281c CLSSignalHandler + 246
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x03d45deb _sigtramp + 43
5   UIKit                           0x01d7f7e0 -[UIViewController _popoverController] + 9
6   UIKit                           0x01d7f85b -[UIViewController _popoverController] + 132
```

CONTINUES for 503 more items - the body limit was reached

```
509 UIKit                           0x01d7f85b -[UIViewController _popoverController] + 132
510 UIKit                           0x01d7f85b -[UIViewController _popoverController] + 132
511 UIKit                           0x01d7f85b -[UIViewController _popoverController] + 132

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e72992 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x03af7f36 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 238
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x03af7c72 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 60

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e72046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e35dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e39cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:: com.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e6cf7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e6c16c mach_msg + 68
2   AppName                         0x001c0f8e CLSMachExceptionServer + 151
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e345fb _pthread_body + 144
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e34485 _pthread_start + 130
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e39cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e72046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e35dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e39cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e6cf7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e6c16c mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x036a8d69 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169
3   CoreFoundation                  0x036ae2c1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1185
4   CoreFoundation                  0x036ad9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
5   CoreFoundation                  0x036ad7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   Foundation                      0x02b93ece +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 381
7   Foundation                      0x02befa07 -[NSThread main] + 76
8   Foundation                      0x02bef966 __NSThread__main__ + 1275
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e345fb _pthread_body + 144
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e34485 _pthread_start + 130
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e39cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x03e71ace __select + 10
1   CoreFoundation                  0x036ec27b __CFSocketManager + 875
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e345fb _pthread_body + 144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e34485 _pthread_start + 130
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x03e39cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x00000003  ecx: 0x11525bcc  edx: 0x03e71286
  edi: 0x11525fe0  esi: 0x003b6194  ebp: 0x11525be8  esp: 0x11525bcc
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000202  eip: 0x03e71286   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x11525c5c

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x000c0025
Trap Number:     132
```

Comment: sure that there is no third party code using it?

Comment: So when you do a system wide code search (not file search) for popoverController in the left hand side xCode panel, it shows no search results?

Comment: Hey guys, no third party code at all and nothing for popoverController in the system wide search :(

Comment: Have you figure this out? I'm having a similar error